# Was this image used in an anti-rape advertising campaign?

Tags: united-states, law, sexual-abuse

I saw an "advertisement" make the rounds on Facebook, which reads:

> Jake was drunk. Josie was drunk. Jake and Josie hooked up. Josie could
>   NOT consent. The next day Jake was charged with RAPE.
>
> A woman who is intoxicated cannot give her legal consent for sex, so
>   proceeding under these circumstances is a crime.
>
> It only takes a single day to ruin your life.

[image: Jake and josie hooked up]

It has the usual barrage of comments by outraged internet-goers standing up for Jake.

Here is an [example website with this image](http://louderwithcrowder.com/jake-josie-hook-drunk-josie-just-raped-jake/#prettyPhoto).

I have trouble believing this is a real ad campaign to raise awareness, because it seems primarily aimed at highlighting inequity in the respective legal system.

Is this ad a hoax or political attack on biased laws? Or is it designed to raise awareness.

Comment: It's hard to read the logo at the bottom, but the site you link claims it says "Coastal Carolina University". But what do you mean by "real" here? Are you asking about the physical existence of the poster? The identity of the group who produced or posted it? The motivations behind doing so? The plausibility of the scenario it describes? The accuracy of the claims made at the bottom of the poster?

Comment: @Nate: Hopefully now clarified.

Comment: A reminder to commenters and others: your opinions on sexual politics aren't of interest here.

Comment: Why do you have trouble believing this is a real ad campaign?  If it is a hoax or attack, who would be the target of the attack and why?

Comment: @gerrit the ad seems to highlight ostensible unfairness in rape laws, and could be used to deride victims of rape. If this campaign is not a hoax I suspect it would be rather damaging to the cause it supposedly supports.

Comment: Sound similar to a case really happened in Italy some time ago and that [ended](http://www.ansa.it/sito/notizie/topnews/2015/07/21/assolti-da-stupro-pg-non-fa-ricorso_50851609-2c68-4fc6-8eec-b9dc6a31a209.html) a few days ago. 6 boys plus one girl utterly drunk, having sex and being convicted for 4 years each after the fact. In the end they were cleared but they *did* risk a lot (and probably spent a lot in lawyers for the 3/4 years of trial).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes.**  But it is out of circulation and no longer used.

According to ["How this school's old anti-rape poster sparked new controversy"](http://www.dailydot.com/lifestyle/anti-rape-poster-reddit-conversations/) in the [The Daily Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_Dot), an internet community newspaper with an [ethics policy](http://media.dailydot.com/ethics-policy/) emphasizing accuracy:

> Debbie Conner, the vice president for campus life and student engagement at Coastal Carolina University, confirmed to the Daily Dot that the poster originated from the university. Conner said it was published in 2008 by the Campus Assault Resource Education Support Coalition, made up of students, faculty, and staff at the university. “It went out of circulation in 2008,” she said.
>
> ...
>
> “The most disconcerting thing for me is that it’s been posted and people don’t understand it’s not something we use or currently endorse on our campus,” she said.

[Ms. Conner's web page at Coastal Carolina University](https://www.coastal.edu/women/officersmembers/dconner.html) gives her role as " associate vice president for University Relations" not "campus life and student engagement".  However it would not be unusual for such titles to be fluid.